# VisualStudio2008 strange of compiler warning, explanation needed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Just a quick Question to the compiler of VisualStudio 2008.

We do have enabled that compiler-warnings are treated as errors which works fine, but today i recognized, that following behaviour:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = 0;
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Compiling this snippet results in only one warning: "The variable 'number' is assigned, but its value is never used".

Can anyone explain the difference to me, why the variable number results to the error, but not the dateTime variable?

Ok, it seems it has something to do with literals. Taking the following code in account:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "Foo";
    string str2 = str1;
}
```

Compiling with both lines leads to no warning, although the variable "str2" is never referenced. If you comment out the line `string str2 = str1;` the warning shows up for variable "str1" is never used.

Comment: What bugs me is that it complies only for the not used integer, but the DateTime isn't used either...

Comment: Alright, that article from Eric Lippert answered me the why VS suppresses the warning. Its just to keep debugging easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Lippert wrote [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/04/23/write-only-variables-considered-harmful-or-beneficial.aspx) on this, so I'll leave it to him to explain:

> Normally C# warns on all variables and
>   fields which are never read, never
>   written, etc. But in this case we
>   suppress the warning on purpose if the
>   assignment is not a constant
>   expression.
>
> This is because there is no good way
>   in the Visual Studio debugger to say
>   "show me the return value of the last
>   function call". Though I would agree
>   were you to sensibly point out that
>   the way to solve this is to fix the
>   debugger, given that I have no ability
>   to fix it, we need a solution in C#
>   for our customers.

See article for further explanation.

Comment: Interestingly, there *is* a way to determine the value of an exception (`$exception`) in the debugger.  So, `catch (Exception ex)` will give a warning if `ex` is never referenced.

Comment: +1 for the link. That's a great addition to the other answers. And thanks for quoting the applicable section in your answer. I wish more people would follow this example.

Answer (score 5):

It is because DateTime.Now is a property, not a literal.  Property getters can have side-effects, simply calling one can be useful by itself.  Not that this is a good idea, it is however not *verboten* to do so and the compiler isn't smart enough to tell whether or not it does.  It can't anyway, it ultimately calls operating system code to obtain the current system time.

Comment: That would explain, why there is no Warning for the DateTime.Now, but not for the variable "dateTime" which is still not referenced.

Comment: Try calling the DateTime.Now property getter without it.

Comment: No, thats not the problem, it could even be a DateTime as literal. It is just, that the compiler does not complain that the variable "dateTime" is not used, like it complains on the variable "number".

Comment: Not sure I follow, what does a literal DateTime look like?  To call a property getter, it has to be used in an expression.  The rhs of an assignment statement for example.  Given that it is legal to rely on the side-effects of the getter, it must also be legal to use the assignment statement.  If that would be outlawed, you'd have to jump through *very* weirdo hoops to call the getter anyway.  Try it.

Comment: But the variable "dateTime" is never referenced like the variable "number" is, therefore should the same error come up for it. I can't follow what the getter of DateTime.Now should have to do with it.

Comment: But of course you're right, theres no literal for a DateTime, see the example with strings for it, same behaviour.

Comment: Same idea, assigning a reference has side effects as well.  Now for the garbage collector.

Comment: This has nothing to with the garbage collector or the compiler. Theoretically the warning should come up, but is suppressed explicitly.

Comment: Sigh, this has everything to do with side-effects.  Post to connect.microsoft.com to ask for design changes.  You do need to bring a compelling argument though, changing this is deeply breaking.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the statement `int number = 0;` is completely side-effect free and can be identified as superfluous by the compiler. `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;` on the other hand, is an evaluation of a static property and could potentially execute other code, thus compiler does not identify it as an unused variable. In other words, while the variable might be unused, the act of assigning it could potentially do something else.

Answer (score -3):

DateTime.Now is a reference. I might be wrong since i have no experience with C# but i don't think you're creating a new object when using DateTime.Now.

Comment: Also, the warning explicitly states "the variable 'number'